# flyway-9.21.2 updates CURRENT_SCHEMA in Db2

Tags: db2, flyway, db2-luw

I upgraded to flyway-9.21.2 and a migration that replaces an external function written in Java fails because db2 can not locate the jar file for the implementation. This works in 8.4.1 and I think I isolated the error down to that CURRENT_SCHEMA is different. Created a dummy migration like:

VALUES CURRENT_SCHEMA;

deliberate cause error

and when I run in 8.4.1, I get:

```
#> flyway-8.4.1 
     -defaultSchema=NYA_FLYWAY 
     -schemas=DB2INST1,NYA_FLYWAY 
     -table=FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY 
     -driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver 
     -url=jdbc:db2://nya-01:50000/nya 
     -user=db2inst1 -password=${passwd} 
     -jarDirs=/home/lejo0004/. 
     -locations="filesystem:/home/lejo0004/Project/db-legacy/nya/src/main/resources/db/migration" migrate

+----------+
| 1        |
+----------+
| DB2INST1 |
+----------+
...
```

and for 9.21.2

```
#> flyway-9.21.2 
     -defaultSchema=NYA_FLYWAY 
     -schemas=DB2INST1,NYA_FLYWAY 
     -table=FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY 
     -driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver 
     -url=jdbc:db2://nya-01:50000/nya 
     -user=db2inst1 -password=${passwd} 
     -jarDirs=/home/lejo0004/. 
     -locations="filesystem:/home/lejo0004/Project/db-legacy/nya/src/main/resources/db/migration" migrate

+------------+
| 1          |
+------------+
| NYA_FLYWAY |
+------------+
...
```

Is this deliberate and is there a way to declare the schema for the history table without affecting registers for the user running the migration?

Comment: Further indications that this is the cause is that adding: `SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = 'DB2INST1'` before trying to replace the function works.

Comment: A possible workaround is to add a callback beforeEachMigrate with: `
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = CURRENT_USER @
`